# Box2dMapObjectParser isometric map - bodies have wrong position and size

Tags: libgdx, box2d, tilemap, isometric, tiled

I'm using `Box2dMapObjectParser` to load **Tiled** objects layer onto my `IsometricTiledMapRenderer`'ed `TiledMap`.
It works OK with a `UnitScale` of 1 but the position is wrong and some shapes have weird rotation and size.

**Map in Tiled:**
[image]

**Map in game:**
[image]

I've found [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172482/box2d-wrong-body-rotation) but the answer is unfortunately far from being clear, at least to me.

Relevant code:

```
mParser.load(mWorld, mMap);
mRenderer = new IsometricTiledMapRenderer(mMap, mParser.getUnitScale());
```

Notice the 'Ellipse' is not drawn at all, the Rectangle is way off and Polygons/Polylines are just not positioned right.

Did anyone experience the same issue and/or have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to set the view before rendering:

`mRenderer.setView((OrthographicCamera) viewport.getCamera());`


Here's an example for isometric maps: https://bitbucket.org/dermetfan/somelibgdxtests/src/abbdb3451f2bb21c51ce004ce2b3f57d3e2cb841/core/src/net/dermetfan/someLibgdxTests/screens/Box2DMapObjectParserSimpleIsometricTest.java
And the map: https://bitbucket.org/dermetfan/somelibgdxtests/src/abbdb3451f2bb21c51ce004ce2b3f57d3e2cb841/android/assets/assets/maps/Box2DMapObjectParserIsometric.tmx


Also remember the `Box2DMapObjectParser` does not support rotated objects.

Comment: @dermetfan thanks for taking the time to check this out and reply. I didn't forget the renderer.setView but I'll look into your example and hopefully it'll hold the answer.

Comment: @dermetfan any plans for fixing the issue?

Comment: @george not currently... https://bitbucket.org/dermetfan/libgdx-utils/issues/16/#comment-29170864